# Magento 2 custom EAV to category tree API

Tags: magento2, category, api, category-tree

I have two custom field `sw_menu_icon_img` and `sw_menu_icon_hover_img` on `Category` in Magento 2 to store the menu icons.

I tried to override `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` and `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Tree` prepareCollection() + getTree() to include the custom fields, but Magento in Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest processApiRequest() line 308 converts the array and remove the elements that don't have getters in `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface'.

My search results didn't give me anything. Does anyone know how to append custom attributes to the API result ?